# How do I force traffic intended for one NIC to never travel through a second NIC?

Tags: networking, routing, network-adapter

The setup: I have a computer with Windows and two NICs; let's call them NIC1 and NIC2. NIC1 is used to interface with the corporate network, and NIC2 is used to interact with some equipment we'll call "the device". NIC1 uses DHCP, and NIC2 is assigned a static ip with no default gateway. The device on NIC2 is connected directly. I'm running some software on my computer that performs diagnostics on the device connected to NIC2, and occassionaly this requires the device to go through a reset/reboot cycle. When this happens, the diagnostic software will poll to see when the device reconnects.

The problem:  Sometimes it takes a little longer for the device to finish this reset/reboot cycle, and if the device is still down when the software polls it, the OS goes from looking for it through NIC 2, where it should be, and starts looking on NIC 1.

The plot thickens: This would all be fine except that the device has a very common IP address, like 192.168.1.1, and people keep attaching equipment to the network with the same IP. I've tried to get the IT deparment to prevent the use of this IP on the network, or provide me with some other relief, to no avail. So when the software I'm running tries to connect to my device and it happens to still be finishing up its reset and doesn't respond, and Windows goes looking for it elsewhere, it actually finds it! Only it isn't it, it's something else with the same darn IP address. So then, a few seconds later when the device I want to talk to does come back up, the software is too busy talking to something else, and I get timeouts, and cascading failures, and all other kinds of headaches.

I'm tired of trying to fight the system through administrative controls or policy, so now I am looking for a technical fix.

So my question is this: is it possible to force traffic on a certain subnet, say 192.168.1.xxx, to always go through NIC 2 and never to even try to go through NIC 1 no matter what? Not even if it can't find what it was looking for on NIC 2?

Limitations and things I've already tried:

I need both NICs active simultaneously. Data I'm collecting is stored in a database on the network. I need NIC2 to collect data and NIC1 to store it.

For various reasons, both technical and political, I cannot change the IP addresses of any of my equipment, not even the device.

I do have complete control over my station, and I've tried to set up routing tables, but those only seem to control priority of where the OS starts looking, and does not control where it is and isn't possible to look. As far as I know there is no "don't use this interface to find this destination IP" entry you can put into a routing table.

Comment: Are the NICs actually configured for different local subnets, or are they both "192.168.1.xxx" as you say?

Comment: Yes, NIC1 using DHCP is using a different subnet, along the lines of 172.xxx.xxx.xxx

Comment: Have you considered IPv6?

Comment: Unfortunately IPv6 is not an option at this time. The device I am trying to communicate with is an in house developed product I have no power or influence over. It must be 192.168.1.1 and it must be IPv4.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem: Sometimes it takes a little longer for the device to finish this reset/reboot cycle, and if the device is still down when the software polls it, the OS goes from looking for it through NIC 2, where it should be, and starts looking on NIC 1.

Connect the device through a cheap Ethernet switch. This will ensure that the Ethernet link seen by your OS never goes down, even if the device reboots. That will allow routes through NIC 2 to always remain valid.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I added an Ethernet switch between the computer and the device, but do not see any discernable change in behavior.

Comment: @ssmquasar What OS are you using? If an interfacs is *up* with an IP in the target's net, then no indirect route through a different NIC should be tried. I just checked: After `sudo ifconfig eth0:1 8.8.8.7/24 up` I cannot ping Google's 8.8.8.8 any more

Comment: But the interface isn't up. Even with the switch in place, if the device is down, the interface appears as "disconnected". When it is disconnected it's entry does not appear in the routing table.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve my desired functionality by deleting the default route of 0.0.0.0/0.

I then created a routing table with entries to direct non-192.0.0.0/255 traffic to the external interface. I did this with 9 entries with the following IP/masks:

- 0.0.0.0/2
- 64.0.0.0/2
- 128.0.0.0/2
- 224.0.0.0/3
- 208.0.0.0/4
- 200.0.0.0/5
- 196.0.0.0/6
- 194.0.0.0/7
- 193.0.0.0/8

I then added a separate rout entry for

- 192.168.1.0/24

The only troubling side effect is that the NCSI indicates no internet connectivity, even though I can access any page I can think of, including the locations that documentation indicates NCSI uses to determine connectivity, [www.msftconnecttest.com/connecttest.txt](http://www.msftconnecttest.com/connecttest.txt) and http://www.msftncsi.com/ncsi.txt

Obviously I've interfered with the connectivity of some, as yet unkown, path that NCSI uses, but traffic intended for 192.168.1.1 never looks outward, even when the device is completely disconnected, which is the functionality I needed.

Comment: great solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have `eth0` configured by DHCP with some 172.16.x.x address and your target has address 192.168.1.1 and is directly connected to `eth1`.

- Configure `eth1` as 192.168.1.2/30
- Configure a subinterface `eth0:1` with 192.168.1.5/29

Now your box will normally try to contact the target via the most specific route, i.e., via eth1.
If eth1 has no link because the target is down, the second best route kicks in, which is via `eth0:1` - and fails because the "wrong" 192.168.1.1 box is behind some router from that nic. Unless eth0:1 is also down, but that should mean that eth0 has no link either.

Con: Apparently 192.168.1.1 is also a valid address in your main network. Your box cannot reach addresses 192.168.1.0 - 192.168.1.7 with the method described above. Without eth0:1, only the minimal range 192.168.1.0 - 192.168.1.3 would be dysfunctional.